# Shutdown on BURG

Tags: grub, linux-mint

I'm using [BURG](https://code.google.com/p/burg/) in my computer with 2 partitions: a Windows 7 and a Linux Mint 17 as well as the Sora theme. Everything works perfectly, except the `shutdown` button. When using the `halt` command, it freezes the computer. When using the `poweroff` command, it returns to the OS selection screen.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

By the way: How can I remove the F2 shortcut from BURG? I don't want people changing my theme.

**Note:** I could remove the F2 shortcut editing the file `/boot/burg/themes/conf.d/10_hotkey`, but my `shutdown` problem wasn't solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I found on a website that I had to add `reboot=bios` to my `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` field in my `/etc/default/burg` file, like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=791 reboot=bios"
```

Here is my reference (that problem also happens with GRUB):
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Fixing_reboot.2Fshutdown_freezes

Answer (score 0):

BURG uses bios apm service to shutdown, but this function is not implemented for some notebook and netbook.

"BURG uses BIOS APM service to shutdown, but this function is not implemented for some notebooks and netbooks."

https://bugs.launchpad.net/burg/+bug/604164

Comment: But that happened to me using a PC (almost 7 different PCs in fact)